# In VS codes terminal how to display the directory showing line on the new line and not on the last line of output?

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, visual-studio-code

In vs code's terminal the line which shows the directory(the line which takes input when opened fresh) is being displayed on the last line of output. Normally the directory should be displayed on the next line after the output. In my vs code the last output line itself shows the directory line and waits for input..  Is there any way to change this weird terminal behavior? Thanks in advance.. I am new to command line and lack proper terminologies.. sorry.. please ask if something feels unclear..

Comment: This is clearly not the standard behaviour. How did you achieve it?

Comment: This is right after install.. nothing done...thats very weird I know... but is there anyway to change it..it looks weird...